# List all the corresponding numbers which fall within a month

Tags: excel

I have a table which looks something like this

```
Month       Item      Haul
June        Gravel    23
July        Asphalt   45
June        Asphalt   5
June        Asphalt   7
September   Asphalt   26
October     Gravel    17
June        Asphalt   21
September   Gravel    25
```

I want to create a function that will list all of the different "`Asphalt`" hauls which happen within a given month in another sheet so that I can calculate the tonnages of each haul. The result should look something like this

```
June
5
7
21
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

With a PivotTable (`Month` for ROWS , `Item` for COLUMNS and `Haul` for Σ VALUES) you can set Σ VALUES to calculate the average for you and if you want the detail for `Asphalt` and `June` just double click on that row/column intersect. The drill down will automatically open in another sheet and the PT will default to a separate sheet unless you choose otherwise.